# Latente heat in pressure cooking

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

When discussing why cooking is faster in pressure cooker, the usual explanation (including on SE) is that higher pressure allows reaching higher temperatures before water starts boiling (typically 120°C instead of 100°C).

I am however surprised that the impact of steam condensation is never mentioned. Due to the large latent heat for condensation, I would expect this process to represent a larger heat transfer than a 20°C temperature increase. Or is it a matter of speeding up the kinetic through the Boltzmann factor, more than a question of increased heat transfer?

Comment: Cooking is faster in a pressure cooker because the temperature is higher.  This is related to the equilibrium vapor pressure vs temperature curve of water.  What is the equilibrium vapor pressure of water at 120 C?  Look it up.  This is the pressure you need to maintain in the pressure cooker in order for the temperature to stay at 120 C.

Comment: This doesn't address my question at all. I know Clapeyron formula and how to relate temperature with saturation pressure. My question is whether the impact of cooking at higher temperature is 1/ speed up the thermal clock or 2/ increase the heat flux towards the ingredients and in that case, why isn't the latent heat due to vapor condensation taken into account?